# C++, Visual Studio 2012 and Error 4700 for class variables in a simple program

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I have a simple code example and I don't know why I get the Error 4700 in Visual Studio 2012?!?

```
error C4700: The uninitialized local variable "a" was used.
error C4700: The uninitialized local variable "b" was used.
```

The code is:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
    int x, y;
};


class B : public A
{
public:
    int z;
};

int main()
{
    cout<<" Using class A and B\n";
    A a;
    cout<<" x= "<<a.x<<"  y= "<<a.y<<"\n";
    B b;
    cout<<" x= "<<b.x<<"  y= "<<b.y<<"  z= "<<b.z<<"\n";
    cout<<"\n End";

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

With "A a;" the object variable "a" should not only be defined but also initialized, because if you don't explicitly have a constructor the default standard constructor is used, right? And then why I get the error, that "a" is not initialized?!?!?
If I add explicitly a default standard constructor for class A and B with empty implementation, I get no errors. This is curious... *smh*

Comment: Your assumption that the default constructor will initialize the members is just wrong.  Memberwise initialization looks like `A a = A();`

Comment: I'm not asking about the members of a class. ;) The object "a" itself is not initialized as the error states.

Comment: And in other code I don't get this error, when I write something like: "MyClass a;" That's why it is so curious. Normally the default standard constructor should be implicitly called, if you don't write any constructor. When I start to compile the code, the above mentioned error is given.

Answer (score 0):

When you define a local object using a default constructor data members of the object are not initialized. So they have arbitrary values and the compiler says about this. To zero-initialize data members of an object you can write

```
A a {};
```

or

```
A a = {};
```

As for class B then it is not an aggregate. So you should write your own default constructor.

```
class B : public A
{
public:
    B() : A(), z( 0 ) {}
    int z;
};
```

Another way is to include initializations in the lcass definitions. For example

```
class A
{
public:
    int x( 0 ), y( 0 );
};
```

Comment: Your suggestion doesn't work in VS2012. I get immediately following error for both cases: `Error: an initialization with "{...}" is for an object of type ""A"" not allowed.`

Comment: Class A is an aggregate so this code A a = {}; shall work with any compiler even if it does not support C++ 2011. As for class B then it is not an aggregate because it has a base class. In this case you should write your own default constructor. For example    class B : public A
  {
  public:
   B() : A(), z( 0 ) {}
   int z;
  };
(),

Comment: @VladfromMoscow in VS2012 you have to use the struct zeroing syntax `A a = { 0 };`

Comment: @ Mgetz It is a wrong statement. C++ allows initialize aggregates with empty braces.

Comment: To all of you again: my question IS NOT about the members. As the error states, the object "a" itself doesn't get initialized. THAT'S the problem. The error is given, when I start the compile routine. When I used similar code, like "MyClass a;", in other small programs, I didn't get any errors. Normally if you write a class with no constructor and then in the main program you write "MyClass a;", the object "a" (forget here the members) is initialized by calling implicitly the default standard constructor, if you don't have any constructor explicitly written in the class "MyClass".

Comment: The code `B() : A(), z( 0 ) {}` works in VS2012. But the code `int x(0), y (0);` doesn't work in VS2012.

Comment: @2-Lee, Maybe. This compiler does not support all features of the C++ 2011 Standard.